# Unity3d - Rigidbody vs CharacterController vs transform.Translate for Sidescroller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, side-scroller

I recently dive into Unity and for my first personal project, I plan to make a 3d sidescroller. The sidescroller however will behave like 2d platformer/sidescroller (only x and y axis). I am wondering which is the best movement controll for the player. Upon searching myself, I found different suggestion by using CharacterController, Rigidbody or even the simple transform.Translate. I am struggling to understand which to use and what each best used for. Thank you in advance for any explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Well is any Physics / collision detection etc involved?

  → this basically rules out going through anything in `Transform` as it would break the collision detection and general feel/correctness of the physics engine.
- `Rigidbody` responds to forces like gravity and `PhysicsMaterial`s providing bounce and friction etc. and usually you apply values more event based (like explosions etc).

  There are a lot of different APIs of how do add forces and velocities to rigidbody objects which gives you a lot of control.

  However, for continuous user input this sometimes is a bit strange to control since you either have to use forces which are strange to calculate (e.g. if you want have a maximum velocity) or absolute velocity input which kinda breaks with the idea of a physics controlled object.
- The `CharacterController` on the other hand does **not automatically** respond to all those physics. It is basically something in between and using [`Move`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) allows to still respond and interact with **collisions**.

  Any gravity, bounce, friction and other forces you need to calculate your self and apply accordingly via passing the resulting movement (= velocity) into the [`Move`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) method **every frame**.

  An alternative is [`SimpleMove`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.SimpleMove.html) which rather applies the gravity automatically.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I have done some reading and I find that CharacterControll may be the best method for 3d sidescroller/platformer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know between Rigidbody and CharacterController. But I would definitely not use Transform.translate, at least if it's more than just jumping and moving left right. The reason why is mostly Physics and the feel of it.

I think you'll have to use the CharacterController but I'm really not sure

Comment: I guess the choice is indeed between Rigidbody and CharacterController. Using transform.Translate ignore the rigidbody and collision making it possible for your object to forcefully phase through other object

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this [Unity Which Movement You Should Choose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixM2W2tPn6c) should help you a lot and answer your questions. Advice: for future plan to create your own movement logic without using any build-in components that is very good practice.